# How to skip rows from all the excel sheets?

Tags: c#, sql, excel, sql-server-2008, ssis

In the excel file there are 3 sheets. A 1, A 2 and A 3.

There are some header in all the sheets. so want to skip first severn rows from all the sheets of the excel file and then import it in the sql server database using ssis.

How can I do this?

In the ssis excel source>tablename or view variable> used a user varibale to get the sheet name automatically so using that user variable cant use the openrowsetvaribale.

Comment: you may try: saveas excel file, remove predefined rows from all sheets, save, then import.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to skip rows on all sheets in an excel file?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can define a [named range](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/exceltips/qt/named_range.htm)(example: `Table1`)

[image]

and then, for `Excel source` component you can select that range (`Data access mode` = `Table or view`) for import:
[image]

or

2) You can select `Data access mode` = `SQL command` and define desired range thus:

`SELECT * FROM  [Sheet1$B8:C11]`

[image]

Comment: But this is for only one sheet. Want to do the same thing for all the sheets. is there anyway to do the things for all sheets at a time?